# getStaticProps() as component?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

It is possible to put getStaticProps as a component?
I have in getStaticProps bellow code, and I want to share this code between several views:

```js
import fs from "fs";
import matter from "gray-matter";
import Link from "next/link";

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const files = fs.readdirSync("notes");

  const notes = files.map((fileName) => {
    const slug = fileName.replace(".md", "");
    const readFile = fs.readFileSync(`notes/${fileName}`, "utf-8");
    const {
      data: { title },
    } = matter(readFile);
    return {
      slug,
      title,
    };
  });

  return {
    props: {
      notes,
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: You should be able to put it in it's own file and then in the files you use it, put `export { getStaticProps } from "../foo/bar/markdownStaticProps";` (replace with path and filename of your choice)